# pick a location from google map in google forms

Tags: forms, google-maps, location, google-forms

I am trying to create a google form where people will write information about the business they own. I want this form to locate the user and pass me the location on google maps, and to allow the user to pick the business location from google maps in case he/she was not at their shops when filling the form.

How can i do that?

Comment: Not enough information. Please show what you've attempted so far.  Refer to [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: see this link www.jotform.me/rayanmb/e-dsr

Comment: the same way the map is shown on this form where people will chose a place on a map